# Tensorflow Recommender - Saving large model with ScaNN index - memory bottleneck

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a relatively large TF retrieval model using the TFRS library. It uses a [ScaNN](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann) layer for [indexing the recommendations](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/api_docs/python/tfrs/layers/factorized_top_k/ScaNN). I am having a system host memory issue when I try to save this model via the [tf.saved_model.save()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save) method. I am running the official TF 2.9.1 Docker Container with TFRS on a VM in the cloud. I have 28 GB of memory to try to save the model.

[Here is the quickstart example:](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/quickstart)

Basically we create the first embedding

```
user_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
    # We add an additional embedding to account for unknown tokens.
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, embedding_dimension)
])
```

Then create the model

```
class MovielensModel(tfrs.Model):

  def __init__(self, user_model, movie_model):
    super().__init__()
    self.movie_model: tf.keras.Model = movie_model
    self.user_model: tf.keras.Model = user_model
    self.task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = task

  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["user_id"])
    # And pick out the movie features and pass them into the movie model,
    # getting embeddings back.
    positive_movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features["movie_title"])

    # The task computes the loss and the metrics.
    return self.task(user_embeddings, positive_movie_embeddings)
```

Next we create the ScaNN indexing layer

```
scann_index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.ScaNN(model.user_model)

scann_index.index_from_dataset(
  tf.data.Dataset.zip((movies.batch(100), movies.batch(100).map(model.movie_model)))
)

# Get recommendations.
_, titles = scann_index(tf.constant(["42"]))
print(f"Recommendations for user 42: {titles[0, :3]}")
```

Finally the model is sent out to be saved

```
# Export the query model.
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp:
   path = os.path.join(tmp, "model")

   # Save the index.
   tf.saved_model.save(
      index,
      path,
      options=tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(namespace_whitelist=["Scann"])
   )

   # Load it back; can also be done in TensorFlow Serving.
   loaded = tf.saved_model.load(path)

   # Pass a user id in, get top predicted movie titles back.
   scores, titles = loaded(["42"])

   print(f"Recommendations: {titles[0][:3]}")
```

This is the problem line:

```
   # Save the index.
   tf.saved_model.save(
      index,
      path,
      options=tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(namespace_whitelist=["Scann"])
   )
```

I'm not sure if there is a memory leak or what, but when I train my model on 5M+ records... I can watch the host system memory spike to 100% and the process is killed. If I train on a smaller dataset... there is no problem, so I know the code is okay.

Can anyone suggest how to get around the memory bottleneck when saving a large ScaNN retrieval model, so I can eventually load the model back in for inference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saving the TF model after training was completed. You just need the saved model to get trained weights from the model.

You can try the following code:

```
    sku_ids = df['SKU_ID']
    sku_ids_list = sku_ids.to_list()
    q = embedding(sku_ids, output_mode='distance_matrix')
    dist_mat = tf.cast(q, tf.float32)
    tree = scann.Scann(n_tables=scann_tables_file_name,
                      n_clusters_per_table=scann_clusters_file_name,
                      dimension=embedding_dimensions,
                      space_type=dist_mat.dtype,
                      metric_type=tf.float32,
                      random_seed=seed,
                      transport_dtype=tf.float32,
                      symmetrize_query_and_dataset=True,
                      num_neighbors_per_table=scann_tables_number_of_neighbors)

    q = tree.build_index(dist_mat)
    p = tree.run(dist_mat)

    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        scann.Dense(1, use_bias=False, activation='linear', dtype=tf.float32),
        keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')
    ])

    model.compile(
        keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
        'binary_crossentropy', metrics=[metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

    idx = -1
    number_of_epochs = 10
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)
    optimizer_state = None
    random_seed = seed
    callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
            monitor='binary_accuracy', mode='max',
            patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)]
    batch_size = 1000
    total_records = len(sku_ids)
    epochs = number_of_epochs
    epochs_completed = 0
    while epochs_completed &lt; epochs:
        idx += 1
        if idx * batch_size &gt;= total_records:
            idx = 0
            epochs_completed += 1
            optimizer_state = None
        print("training epoch: {}".format(idx))
        q_ = tree.transform(dist_mat[idx * batch_size : (idx + 1) * batch_size])
        p_ = tree.transform(dist_mat)
        y = p_[:, :, 0]
        print("callbacks: {}".format(callbacks))
        print("model compile: {}".format(model.compile))
        model.fit(q_, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size,
                  callbacks=callbacks,
                  validation_split=0.2,
                  verbose=0,
                  shuffle=True,
                  initial_epoch=0,
                  steps_per_epoch=None,
                  validation_steps=None,
                  validation_batch_size=None,
                  validation_freq=1,
                  class_weight=None,
                  max_queue_size=10,
                  workers=1,
                  use_multiprocessing=False,
                  shuffle=False, initial_epoch=0)


    sku_ids_tensor = tf.constant(sku_ids_list,
                                 shape=[len(sku_ids_list), 1],
                                 dtype=tf.int64)

    print("sku_ids_tensor shape: {}".format(sku_ids_tensor.shape))
    tree_tensor = tree.transform(dist_mat)
    print("tree_tensor shape: {}".format(tree_tensor.shape))
    predictions = tf.constant(tf.sigmoid(model.predict(tree_tensor)),
                              dtype=tf.float32)
    print("predictions shape: {}".format(predictions.shape))
    recommendations = tf.concat([sku_ids_tensor, predictions], axis=1)
    print("recommendations shape: {}".format(recommendations.shape))

    retrieval_user_sku_recommendations = []

    for u in unique_sku_list:
        print("u: {}".format(u))
        user_skus = sku_ids[sku_ids.isin([u])]
        print("user_skus: {}".format(user_skus))
        user_sku_id = user_skus.index[0]
        print("user_sku_id: {}".format(user_sku_id))
        user_sku_recommendations = recommendations[sku_ids.isin([u])]
        print("user_sku_recommendations: {}".format(user_sku_recommendations))
        retrieval_user_sku_recommendations.append(user_sku_recommendations)

    retrieval_skus_df = pd.DataFrame(sku_ids_list, columns=['SKU_ID'])
    retrieval_skus_df['SKU_ID'] = retrieval_skus_df['SKU_ID'].astype(int)
    retrieval_skus_df.head()

    user_sku_recommendations_list = []
    for sku in retrieval_skus_df['SKU_ID']:
        for u in unique_sku_list:
            print("sku: {}".format(sku))
            print("u: {}".format(u))
            if sku == u:
                user_skus = sku_ids[sku_ids.isin([sku])]
                user_sku_id = user_skus.index[0]
                user_sku_recommendations = recommendations[sku_ids.isin([sku])]
                user_sku_recommendations_list.append(user_sku_recommendations)

    tf.saved_model.save(model, ss_model_dir)
```